# In Yahoo Mail, can I create subfolders?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I would like to create subfolders for additional organization options ie,

Kids, having the following sub folders:

- education
- sports
- etc.

The number of folders that I use is becoming cumbersome to manage!

Answer (score 2):

If you can setup an email client (e.g., Thunderbird or MS Outlook) that accesses your Yahoo mailbox via the IMAP protocol, you can setup subfolders on that email client.

The subfolders will show up in the Yahoo web mail interface. As far as I can tell, the subfolders work as expected in the Yahoo mail interface, except you can't delete them there (it give an "I'm confused" error).